# Await Execution of a Subcommand and Parse its Output

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, async-await, vscode-extensions, thenable

I'm attempting to run a command line tool and parse the output from `stdout` in order to do something useful with it in a VSCode extension. I'm attempting to create `Flow` objects (defined elsewhere in the code) and append them to `this.flows`; however, the function returns before `this.flows` is set.

```
    getChildren(element?: vscode.TreeItem): Thenable<Flow[]> | Flow[] | null {

        if (element === undefined) {
            exec(commandToRun, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                let flowJson = JSON.parse(stdout); // output is expected in json format
                for (let i =0; i < jsonString.length; ++i) {
                    let f = new Flow(jsonString[i][name], flowJson[i]['description'], vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None);
                    this.flows.push(f);
                }
            }
        }
        return new Promise<Flow[]>(resolve => resolve(this.flows));
    }
```

I believe it need to make use of `await` or `then`, but not sure how to incorporate them to achieve the desired result.

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the async version of exec.

Instead, you can use [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) and avoid redundant async-awaits. For example:

```
let stdout = execSync(commandToRun)
let flowJson = JSON.parse(stdout); // output is expected in json format
for (let i =0; i < jsonString.length; ++i) {
    let f = new Flow(jsonString[i][name], flowJson[i]['description'], vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None);
    this.flows.push(f);
}
```

Comment: I was totally overthinking this. Thank you!